# Validate CTabFolder before switching tabs

Tags: java, tabs, swt

In a `CTabFolder`, I'd like to check the content for unsaved data before the user can switch from one tab to another. SWT does not provide a PreSelection event, as stated [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=193064).

I found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958279/any-workarounds-to-lack-of-preselection-events-in-swt-jface), suggesting to switch back to the old tab when a selection is triggered, validate the data and then perform the desired switch again, if data is valid.

I do understand the general idea of this workaround, however, it is not working for me. `oldPageIndex` and `newPageIndex` do always have the same value, though I did not click on the same tab.

```
this.tabContainer.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
      int oldPageIndex = tabContainer.getSelectionIndex();
      int newPageIndex = tabContainer.indexOf((CTabItem)event.item);

      // Here: oldPageIndex == newPageIndex

      ...
   }
});
```

Is this workaround still working or is there anything I could possibly be doing wrong? Or maybe, has there been any fix for a real PreSelection event in the meantime? I tried using `event.doit`, but the `SelectionEvent` is fired, when the tabs have been switched already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selection listener but as you have found the `getSelectionIndex()` does not give you the old tab. So you will have to maintain the old tab index yourself.

This is the technique used by the Eclipse `FormEditor`.

Comment: All right, that's what I'm actually doing right now anyway. Did that workaround ever work, though? It got me confused, this other SO post was accepted way back in 2010.

Comment: I don't know for sure, certainly FormEditor has always remembered the last page itself.